# gvim search match multiple characters using regex

Tags: regex, search, vim

I am trying to search in gvim for the following pattern:

```
arrayA[*].entryx
```

hoping it would match the following:

```
arrayA[size].entryx  
arrayA[i].entryx
arrayA[index].entryx
```

but it prints message saying Pattern not found even though the above lines are present in the file.

```
arrayA[.].entryx
```

only matches arrayA[i].entryx
i.e. with only one character between [] braces.

What should I do to match multiple characters between [] braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the PCRE expression detail

```
/arrayA\[[^]]*]\.entryx/
         ^^^^^            # 0 or more characters before a ']'
       ^^      ^^         # Escaped '[' & '.'
              ^           # Closing ']' -- does not need to be escaped
 ^^^^^^          ^^^^^^   # Literal parts
```

If you want to look for `arrayA[X].entryx` where, there is at least on character in the `[]`,
You need to replace  `\[[^]]*` with `\[[^]]\+`

ps: Note my edit -- I've changed the `\*` to just `*` -- you don't escape that either.
But, you need to escape the `+`  `:-)`

---

`Update` on your comment:
While my comment answers your question on escaping `]` broadly,
for more detail look at [Perl Character Class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) details.
Specifically, the `Special Characters Inside a Bracketed Character Class` section.
Rules of what needs to be escaped change after a `[`character starts a Character Class (CCL).

Comment: Why doesnt the closing ']' need to be escaped but the opening '[' should be escaped? Thank you.

Comment: because when you write the first `[` the pcre-parser can not know if you mean the meta character for CCLs or the literal character. But, a closing `]` is not ambiguous -- you have either started a CCL or not. When you don't escape the former, the parse assumes it to be the meta-character.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` repeats the previous character; and `[` starts a character class.  So, you need something more like:

```
/arrayA\[[^]]*]\.entryx/
```

That looks for a literal `[`, a series of zero or more characters other than `]`, a literal `]`, a literal `.` and the `entryx`.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that in VIM you need to scape some special characters, such as `[`, `]`, `{`, `}` and `.`. As said before the `*`repeats the previous character, with this you can simply use the `/arrayA\[.*\]\.entryx`, but the `*` is greedy character, it may match some strange things, add the following line to your file and you'll understand: `arrayA[size].entryx  = arrayB[].entryx`

A "safer" Regular Expression would be:

```
/arrayA\[.\{-\}\]\.entryx
```

The `.\{-\}` matches any character in a non-greedy way, witch is safer for some cases.